# how to suspend a thread without killing it

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-2.6

I have several thread executed at the same time. I want to implement a function that saves the state of my thread and stop it knowing that I do not want to kill it (no Thread.stop ()) because I seek also to implement a function that allows stains to continue my thread (since the state where it came to stop)

Comment: If you only tag things with tag:python-2.6 you are unlikely to get many responses. You should also give us the code you have got so far.